# SQL 'like' expression to match all varchar values (i.e. no actual filtering done)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-like

I want to know which expression I can use with `like`, which will **always** match. That is, it doesn't actually filter anything out.

So for example, suppose if the following SQL returns 1000 records ...

```
select * from rts.Address
```

... then this should also return 1000 records ...

```
select * from rts.Address where StreetName like 'likeExpressionHere'
```

I tried using this:

```
select * from rts.Address where StreetName like '%%'
```

.. but this still did some filtering (i.e. some records were missing) ..

Also, none of the `StreetName` values in the `rts.Address` table are null (i.e. they all have some varchar value in them)

Comment: did you try `like '%'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the `like`, which should work.  It is most likely that the `StretName` takes on NULL values.

You can't fix this with like, although you could do something like:

```
where coalesce(StreetName, '<NULL>') like '%'
```

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on your data, but `where Streetname like '%'` should work.

If for example the column is nullable, you will need to add

`where StreetName like '%' OR StreetName IS NULL`

Answer (score -1):

The question seem to very generic .Provide more info such as the content of table . Also the like or where in sql can tweaked according to your need hence it should not be a big deal . Below is the wilWildcard   Description
%   A substitute for zero or more characters
_   A substitute for exactly one character
[charlist]  Any single character in charlist
[^charlist]
or

[!charlist]

Any single character not in charlistd card usage table . Please refer same for more info